# Package tar.gz into a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, installation, tar

I'd like to know how to package a tar.gz file into a shell script, just like idk**.bin does. So I can deliver the program in one shell file instead of tar.gz

Comment: The basic concept is to write a shell script that knows how to cut the tarball off the end of the file and then just cat the script and archive together.

Comment: In some settings it could be a good idea to base64 encode the tarball before adding it so non-printable characters in the payload do not cause problems when the script is displayed.

Comment: The first time I ever saw a .sh file with a huge payload I was astonished.  So I think this is a valuable question because I can only imagine others will be equally surprised.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a [Linux Journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/1005818) explaining how to do this in detail, with code for packing the payload, etc. As Etan Reisner says in his comment, the extraction/installation script knows how to cut its tail off to obtain the payload which was concatenated earlier. Here's an example of how that works:

```
#!/bin/bash
# a self-extracting script header

# this can be any preferred output directory
mkdir ./output_dir

# determine the line number of this script where the payload begins
PAYLOAD_LINE=`awk '/^__PAYLOAD_BELOW__/ {print NR + 1; exit 0; }' $0`

# use the tail command and the line number we just determined to skip
# past this leading script code and pipe the payload to tar
tail -n+$PAYLOAD_LINE $0 | tar xzv -C ./output_dir

# now we are free to run code in output_dir or do whatever we want

exit 0

# the 'exit 0' immediately above prevents this line from being executed
__PAYLOAD_BELOW__
```

Note the use of `$0` to refer to the script itself.

To create the installer in the first place, you need to concatenate the code above and the tarball you want to install/deliver. If the script above is called extract.sh, and the payload is called payload.tar.gz, then this command would do the trick:

```
cat extract.sh payload.tar.gz > run_me.sh
```

Comment: Not exactly as written, Jahid. You would need to modify the command after the pipe operator on the line that starts with `tail` to invoke the program that can handle the archive you have selected. Also if that program cannot handle input on stdin, then you would need to write the archive to a file and then invoke your archive handler on that file.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this too:

```
#!/bin/bash
BASEDIR=`dirname "${0}"`
cd "$BASEDIR"

payload=$1
script=$2
tmp=__extract__$RANDOM

[ "$payload" != "" ] || read -e -p "Enter the path of the tar archive: " payload
[ "$script" != "" ] || read -e -p "Enter the name/path of the script: " script

printf "#!/bin/bash
PAYLOAD_LINE=\`awk '/^__PAYLOAD_BELOW__/ {print NR + 1; exit 0; }' \$0\`
tail -n+\$PAYLOAD_LINE \$0 | tar -xvz
#you can add custom installation command here

exit 0
__PAYLOAD_BELOW__\n" > "$tmp"

cat "$tmp" "$payload" > "$script" && rm "$tmp"
chmod +x "$script"
```

If you save this file as `t2s`, then you can use it like this:

```
t2s test.tar.gz install.sh
```

Running `install.sh` will extract the content in the current directory. You can run custom installation scripts too if you need. You will have to add them in the `printf` section properly.

If you need to do it for other compression types (`.tar.bz2` etc..), you will need to edit the `z` option in the section:

```
tail -n+\$PAYLOAD_LINE \$0 | tar xzv
#it's inside a quote and $ needs to be printed, so you will need to use \
```

For example:

For .tar.bz2:

```
tail -n+\$PAYLOAD_LINE \$0 | tar xjv 
#it's inside a quote and $ needs to be printed, so you will need to use \
```

For .tar

```
tail -n+\$PAYLOAD_LINE \$0 | tar xv 
#it's inside a quote and $ needs to be printed, so you will need to use \
```

For information on this option you can see the man page of tar:

```
man tar
```

> I have made it into a [tool](http://neurobin.github.io/tartos/) to automate these tasks.

Comment: Nice approach, Jahid, all in one file. +1. But I don't think you need the line that says `pay=\`cat $payload\``. First of all, `$pay` is never used, and second, if `$payload` is a multigigabyte file then you might have trouble loading it into a variable. ;)