# How to unpack the tgz file present in a shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, tar, unpack

I have a .sh build file which is basically a tar.gz file wrapped up with few lines of shell code.
I know how to pack a tar.gz into shell [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418050/package-tar-gz-into-a-shell-script), but how to do the reverse i.e., unpack the tgz file present in the .sh file?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: note that your link just points to your own question

Comment: The question is missing the necessary input, giving an example would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, if in case anyone needs it!

Get the number of lines of shell code in the .sh file, say n lines.
Now delete first n=21 lines of .sh file and save the rest in the other file say sample.tar like:

```
sed '1,21d' sc_300026_smca.sh > sample.tar
```

Now we'll end up with sample.tar, the required file.